# Why is my SWF file not showing?

Tags: 7, files

So I have a SWF file, the path is working fine, I have it displayed in the main node just fine.

However when I try to put it in the right side bar, it just does not display.

Could it be a height/width issue? What's the optimal way to display it? PHP code? filtered HTML?

Sorry if this question is a bit vague - I'm trying to understand more of what would cause a video to not display at all, even in the source.

Comment: What input formats are you using in the main node and sidebar?

Comment: Currently plain text and full HTML respectively, but I've used plain text before.

Comment: Try setting the sidebar block to the same input format as the node. If that doesn't work, it's not an input format issue. Is the code for it showing up if you inspect it with Firebug?

Comment: No, it isn't. Though it appears like the sidebar itself may not be displaying (I have two versions, one for this page, as a test)